# Twilio Voicemail (Twilio Number to Cell Phone)

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

When someone calls my Twilio phone number, I'd like to have it forward to my personal cell phone. I know I can do that with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response action="/voicemail" timeout="5">
    <Dial>
        <Number>415-123-4567</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

where 415-123-4567 is my personal cell phone number.

My `/voicemail` Twiml looks is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Say>
    Please leave a message at the beep. 
    Press the star key when finished. 
</Say>
<Record
    action="/thankyou"
    method="GET"
    maxLength="20"
    finishOnKey="*"
/>
<Say>I did not receive a recording.</Say>
</Response>
```

This works fine, with one problem.

If someone calls my Twilio number, my personal phone rings. If I double click the power button on my phone within 5 seconds, it sends the caller to my personal voicemail (instead of my Twilio voicemail).

In this example, I set the timeout to 5. I'm guessing that I have to specify a timeout number (there's probably no way to trigger the /voicemail to execute right before my personal voicemail goes off), or it won't trigger the voicemail set up on Twilio. I don't have a problem with that because I can increase the time from 5 seconds to 20 seconds. If I do that and someone calls my Twilio number, then I double click the power button on my phone within 20 seconds, it will play my personal cell phone's ringtone and not my Twilio ringtone.

Comment: Hey David, not sure what your question is here. What's going wrong?

Comment: Hi Phil, The problem I'm trying to stop is having a possible client call my Twilio number and reach my personal cell phone voicemail. I want anyone who calls my Twilio number to only hear my Twilio voicemail and never to hear my personal voicemail. If someone calls and I double click the power button on my phone, it goes straight to my personal voicemail instead of my Twilio voicemail. I appreciate your help.

Comment: So, the issue there is that when you double click the power button, that sends the call to your personal voicemail. To Twilio, that is an answered call, it is just answered by your voicemail, so the `<Dial>` handles it as such and connects the two calls. If you want calls that come to your Twilio number to go to your Twilio voicemail, then you're going to need to leave the phone alone until the `<Dial>` times out.

Comment: Okay thanks Phil. That's what I thought, but I just wanted to be sure that I'm not missing anything.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help out and hope you can get it to work in a way that does work for you.